# Symfony2. Populate ManyToMany connection table using data fixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I have following entities with many to many relation:
**User**

```
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Role", mappedBy = "users")
  *
  * @var ArrayCollection $roles;
  */
 private $roles;
```

**Role**

```
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "User", inversedBy = "roles")
  * 
  * @var ArrayCollection $users
  */
 protected $users;
```

Doctrine generated 3 tables:
user
role
user_role

Then I added data fixture:

```
class FixtureLoader implements FixtureInterface {
     public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {

          $role = new Role();
          $role->setName('Администратор');
          $role->setRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

          $manager->persist($role);

          $user = new User();
          $user->setUsername('ahmed');
          $user->setEmail('ahmed@umahanov.com');
          $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
          $user->setIsActive(false);

          $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512',true,10);
          $password = $encoder->encodePassword('admin', $user->getSalt());
          $user->setPassword($password);
          //$user->getUserRoles()->add($role);
          $user->addRole($role);
          $manager->persist($user);

          $manager->flush();  

     }
}
```

When I load it using console, only 2 tables populated with data, but user_role table, which keep manytomany relations is empty.

How to solve this? Or I need to populate it myself?

```
/**
 * Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {

     /**
      * @var integer
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Role", mappedBy = "users")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
      *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
      *   )
      * @var ArrayCollection $roles;
      */
     private $roles;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true)
      */
     private $username;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=32)
      */
     private $salt;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=88)
      */
     private $password;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
      */
     private $email;

     /**
      * @var boolean
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
      */
     private $isActive;

     public function __construct() {
          $this->isActive = false;
          $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
          $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
     }

     /**
      * Get roles (array)
      *
      * @return array
      */
     public function getRoles() {
          return $this->roles->toArray();
     }

     /**
      * @inheritDoc
      */
     public function eraseCredentials() {

     }

     /**
      * @see \Serializable::serialize()
      */
     public function serialize() {
          return serialize(array(
                      $this->id,
                  ));
     }

     /**
      * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
      */
     public function unserialize($serialized) {
          list (
                  $this->id,
                  ) = unserialize($serialized);
     }

     /**
      * Get id
      *
      * @return integer
      */
     public function getId() {
          return $this->id;
     }

     /**
      * Set username
      *
      * @param  string $username
      * @return User
      */
     public function setUsername($username) {
          $this->username = $username;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get username
      *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getUsername() {
          return $this->username;
     }

     /**
      * Set salt
      *
      * @param  string $salt
      * @return User
      */
     public function setSalt($salt) {
          $this->salt = $salt;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get salt
      *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getSalt() {
          return $this->salt;
     }

     /**
      * Set password
      *
      * @param  string $password
      * @return User
      */
     public function setPassword($password) {
          $this->password = $password;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get password
      *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getPassword() {
          return $this->password;
     }

     /**
      * Set email
      *
      * @param  string $email
      * @return User
      */
     public function setEmail($email) {
          $this->email = $email;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get email
      *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getEmail() {
          return $this->email;
     }

     /**
      * Set is_active
      *
      * @param  boolean $isActive
      * @return User
      */
     public function setIsActive($isActive) {
          $this->isActive = $isActive;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get is_active
      *
      * @return boolean
      */
     public function getIsActive() {
          return $this->isActive;
     }

     /**
      * Сравнивает пользователя с другим пользователем и определяет
      * один и тот же ли это человек.
      * 
      * @param UserInterface $user The user
      * @return boolean True if equal, false othwerwise.
      */
     public function equals(UserInterface $user) {
          return md5($this->getUsername()) == md5($user->getUsername());
     }

     /**
      * Add roles
      *
      * @param \Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
      * @return User
      */
     public function addRole(\Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles) {
          $this->roles[] = $roles;

          return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Remove roles
      *
      * @param \Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
      */
     public function removeRole(\Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles) {
          $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
     }

}
```

And here is role:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface {

     /**
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      * 
      * @var integer $id
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
      * 
      * @var string $name
      */
     protected $name;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
      * 
      * @var string $role
      */
     protected $role;     

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
      *
      * @var DateTime $createdAt;
      */
     protected $createdAt;

     public function getRole() {

          return $this->role;
     }

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "User", inversedBy = "roles")
      * 
      * @var ArrayCollection $users
      */
     protected $users;


     public function getCreatedAt() {
          return $this->createdAt;
     }

     public function __construct() {
          $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
          $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
     }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(\Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you properly set up getters and setters for both entities?

Comment: They were generated with doctrine console tool. Actually it saves data to role and user tables. So the fixture is correct, but why role_user table is still empty?

Comment: ok, could you post full Role and User entities?

Comment: Geez, that looks fine ... what doctrine / symfony version are you using? Also, try to change all field modifiers from private to protected. I've had a problem once with that, as doctrine couldn't pick up private fields (it does object inspection via reflection).

Comment: did that. updated schema. reloaded fixture. still mysql> select * from role_user;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Try: @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Role", mappedBy = "users", cascade={"persist"}). Also take a look at doctrine/symfony cache and purge it, as well as cached doctrine metadata.

Comment: Cleared doctrine cache(metadata,query,result), symfony cache(app/cache), updated annotation, schema, reloaded fixtures. Thanks, but still no luck(

Comment: sorry, out of ideas :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set related entities, they must be set on the both sides:
For `User` class:

```
 /**
  * Add roles
  *
  * @param \Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
  * @return User
  */
 public function addRole(\Umahanov\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles) {
      $this->roles[] = $roles;
      $roles->addUser($this);

      return $this;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to Symfony and there is too much info at all. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for this answer, I was experiencing the EXACT same problem. Anyway, it feels strange to me that you have to set them on both sides, is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

I do it in a slightly different way and it works for me.
I have one file for the `Role` (called `Groups` in my case) as follow:

```
<?php

class LoadGroupsData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach($this->container->getParameter('my_groups') as $key => $value)
        {
            $group = new Groups();
            $group->setRole($key);
            $group->setName($value);

            $manager->persist($group);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addReference($key, $group);
        }
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And one file for the `Users` as follow:

```
<?php

class LoadUsersData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach($this->container->getParameter('my_users') as $key => $value)
        {
            $user = new Users();
            $user->setUsername($key);

            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($value, $user->getSalt()));

            $user->addRole($this->getReference('ROLE_ADMIN'));

            $manager->persist($user);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

My fixtures are proceed in order: the `Groups` are persisted and flushed and the object stored in an object shared between the fixture. The `Users` are then created and attached to the `Groups` stored in the shared object.

So the main difference with you is that my `Groups` objects (`Role` in your case) are persisted and flushed before trying to set them to the user.